# How prove that for any integer $n$, $\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{n + 1}2\right\rfloor = n$ is true

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Prove that for any integer $n$, the relation below is true. $$\left\lfloor\dfrac n2\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\dfrac{n + 1}2\right\rfloor = n$$

Comment: Consider the cases where $n$ is odd and even separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n$ be an even integer.$\Rightarrow \frac n2$ is an integer and $\frac {n+1}2$ is not an integer.

So, $\lfloor{\frac n2}\rfloor = \frac n2$ and $\lfloor{\frac {n+1}2}\rfloor = \frac n2$ because the greatest integer $\le \frac {n+1}2$ is $\frac n2$. While adding, we get $n$.

---

Similarly for $n$ being an odd integer, $\frac{n+1}{2}$ is an integer $\Rightarrow\lfloor{\frac {n+1}2}\rfloor = \frac {n+1}2$ and $\frac n2$ is not an integer but $\frac{n-1}2$ is an integer $\Rightarrow \lfloor{\frac n2}\rfloor = \frac {n-1}2$. Again while adding, we get $n$

Answer (score 2):

Note that every integer $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is either even or odd. Suppose that the former holds. Then, $\exists\:k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n=2k$. We have
$$\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor{\frac{n+1}{2}}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor{k}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor{k+\frac{1}{2}}\right\rfloor=2k=n$$

Now suppose that $n$ is odd. Then, $\exists\:k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n=2k+1$. We have 
$$\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor{\frac{n+1}{2}}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor{k+\frac{1}{2}}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor{k+1}\right\rfloor=2k+1=n$$

This finishes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to propose a proof by induction, firstly for non-negative integers:

**Base Case:** n = 1 can be checked trivially.

**Induction Hypothesis:** Let it be true for n = k positive integers. Thus $\left\lfloor\dfrac k2\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\dfrac{k + 1}2\right\rfloor = k$

**Induction Step:** Plug in $k + 1$. Thus $\left\lfloor\dfrac {k+1}2\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\dfrac{k + 2}2\right\rfloor = (\left\lfloor\dfrac {k+1}2\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\dfrac{k}2\right\rfloor) + 1 = k + 1$

Now for the negative integers, convert the above form to $\left\lfloor\dfrac {-k}2\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\dfrac{1-k}2\right\rfloor = -k$ for $k >= 1$ and follow the strategy from above.